# Return message to a user

Tags: php, oop

I have the following PHP OOP code and in this I am trying to get a message to the user saying the image is too big.

I really can't find a satisfying answer that can help me on my way.

This is an example that shows how I tried.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for doing this?

**image class:**

```
class image{

    public function checkImageSize($img){

        if($img['size'] > 1500000)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

}// end class image
```

**HTML side**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {

        $img = new image;
        $img->checkImageSize($_FILES['image']);
        $img->otherfunctions();
        $img->anotherfunction();

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `return true;` to the end of your function and then check it:

```
if($img->checkImageSize($_FILES['image'])) {
    $img->otherfunctions();
    $img->anotherfunction();
} else {
    echo "TOO BIG!!!";
    //header("location: somewhere");
    exit;        
}
```

Or the opposite:

```
if($img->checkImageSize($_FILES['image']) === false) {
    echo "TOO BIG!!!";
    //header("location: somewhere");
    exit;
}
$img->otherfunctions();
$img->anotherfunction();
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I have some other image checks like checkIfImage() would i use these functions in the same way? keep putting if statements around them?

Comment: Yes, or put them all in one `if`, or better put the `if`s in a function that checks everything.

Answer (score 3):

As an extension to your class you could do this

```php
<?
//Array for storing data for class to access
$info = array(
  "image" => null
);

//array of errors to be returned
$errors = array(
  "size" => null,
  "other" => null
);

//Set the image
function SetImage($img){
  $this->info["image"] = $img;
}

//Check size of image
function CheckSize(){
  if($this->info["image"] > 1500000){
    //If image is too large populate error
    $this->errors["size"] = "File is too large";
  }else{
    continue;
  }
}

//Check other things
function OtherCheck(){
  if(true){
    continue;
  }else{
    $this->errors["other"] = "Other checks failed";
  }
}

//Check if there are any errors
function CheckErrors(){
  for($i = 0; $i < count($this->errors);$i++){
    if($this->errors[$i] != null){
      //if the value of an error is not null then return true
      //because there is an error present
      return true;
    }
  }
}

//Run all checks
function RunChecks(){
  CheckSize();
  OtherCheck();
  //Check if CheckErrors() returns true
  if(CheckErrors()){
   //If it returns true then print the error array
   print_r($this->errors);
  }
}
?>
```

In an OOP approach I prefer to let the class do all of the heavy lifting

Using this your code would now look like this

```php
$img = new image;
$img->SetImage($_FILES["image"]);
$img->RunChecks();
```

Comment: Oh thanks, also a good way to look at it. Thank you!